# Download manager - prevent termination

Tags: download, download-manager

i am trying to download a large datafile from www.kaggle.com on my Windows 7 system. (12 GB file). I unfortunately am in a location with somewhwat spotty internet, and every 6-7 hours have to unfortunately temporarily put my computer in sleep mode for an hour or so. I have tried different download managers, but suprisingly to me, they each would fully terminate and restart the entire download upon a network failure or a connection breakdown (even after already downloading e.g. 3Gb). Have i just downloaded the wrong download managers - or should i take a different approach?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the server you're downloading from doesn't support resuming downloads, or maybe your download programs don't (but almost every one does, even Firefox should support resume...). The file doesn't change every 6hrs does it?

I had luck in the past by pinging a server whenever a download would slow down - even one ping per minute could be enough, and should be tiny enough to not bother anyone - just **don't** try flooding 100 pings/second for 2 days. But that won't help if it's your whole internet connection that goes down.

I'd look at any different ways to download the file. A torrent, different server, temporarily use a different internet connection, have a friend download it to a USB, or a friend download it and start a (private to you only) torrent...